# python calendar.timegm implementation?

Tags: python, time, calendar

From $PYTHONHOME/lib/python2.7/calendar.py,  timegm is defined as

```
EPOCH = 1970
_EPOCH_ORD = datetime.date(EPOCH, 1, 1).toordinal()


def timegm(tuple):
    """Unrelated but handy function to calculate Unix timestamp from GMT."""
    year, month, day, hour, minute, second = tuple[:6]
    days = datetime.date(year, month, 1).toordinal() - _EPOCH_ORD + day - 1
    hours = days*24 + hour
    minutes = hours*60 + minute
    seconds = minutes*60 + second
    return seconds
```

Is there any reason why days is not calculated as :

```
days = datetime.date(year, month, day).toordinal() - _EPOCH_ORD
```

Can anyone think of cases where the previous expression would break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datetime.date(year, month, day).toordinal()
```

"range checks" that the `day` (combined with year and month) is part of a valid `datetime.date`.

`datetime.date(year, month, 1)` does not -- or rather, only requires that `year` and `month` are valid.

Apparently some user was exploiting this "feature" (of not checking the day) and for the sake of backwards compatibility (with Python2.2!) the developers kept this behavior. See Raymond Hettinger's comment in [commit #27881](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/148d8c0b9647).

PS. You can find the commit that changed this line in `calendar.py` by running

```
hg blame cpython/Lib/calendar.py
```

(provided you've `hg clone`d the CPython repository).

```
10940: def timegm(tuple):
11691:     """Unrelated but handy function to calculate Unix timestamp from GMT."""
11691:     year, month, day, hour, minute, second = tuple[:6]
27881:     days = datetime.date(year, month, 1).toordinal() - _EPOCH_ORD + day - 1
```

Then, to find more about commit #27881, you can search http://hg.python.org/